# AngularJS2 in template handle JSON

Tags: json, typescript, angular

I can handle, JSON from the template, in a similar way to the second code I put?.

---

First code.

This works well when it is used `.json` <kbd>[</kbd> <kbd>]</kbd> and using `.map ()`

```
@Component({
..//
template: `..//
           <li *ngFor="#user of users">
           JSON: {{ user.name }}

          ..//`


  get(){

    this.http.get('lib/sampleResAPI.json')
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(users => this.users = users);
   ..//
  }
```

sampleResAPI.json (used [] <kbd>[</kbd> <kbd>]</kbd> )

```
[
{
  "id": 362,
  "name": "test",
..//
}
]
```

---

but the answer I receive is not [] in `.json`. the alert is displayed, fine with users.name, `alert(this.users.name);` but I'm not able to handle it from the template {{ users.name }} obtain undefined property.

-> second code not found

```
@Component({
..//
template: `..//

           JSON: {{ users.name }}

          ..//`


  get(){

    this.http.get('lib/sampleResAPI.json')
    //.map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(users => this.users = users.json());

    //this.u = JSON.parse(this.users);
    alert(this.users.name);
    ..//
    }
```

sampleResAPI.json not <kbd>[</kbd> <kbd>]</kbd>

```
{
  "id": 362,
  "name": "test",
..//
}
```

there a way to handle `.json`, similar to `user.name` in alert, in template, or am I doing something wrong and that's the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
JSON: {{ user?.name }}
```

to cover the time before `user` is set

Comment: oh my goodnees, I have tried as hundreds of syntax without any result, your answer works great, thanks

Comment: It's the Elvis operator or safe-navigation operator. It evaluestes `.name` only when `user` is != null/undefined. You can't use it everywhere (`user?[x]` for example isn't supported. For this you'd need `user ? user[x] :  null`

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation

Comment: I apply in the second case {{ users?.name }} work fine. In de first code no need for my apply ? I user.name found well

Comment: I don't fully understand your comment. When the field you bind to is set already in the constructor (maybe only  a default value) you don't need `?.` because there is already a value before Angulars first attempt to establish the binding. But when `user` is null for a while and only when the HTTP request returns eventually a value is assigned to `user`, Angular fails when it tries to read `.name` from `user` which is still `null` and throws an exception.

Comment: Sorry for my English  but I think now I understand better, for your coments, maybe not be necessary ? in the first case because I used this * ngFor =

Comment: Right, It won't create that tag anyway when there is no value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand the problem. Could you give us the content of the `users` result for each use case with the JSON pipe operator:

```
@Component({
  ..//
  template: `..//
    JSON: {{ users | json }}
  `
})
```

`users.name` should always return `undefined` since the `name` is a property of elements in the array not on the array itself...

Comment: Thanks for your time the response @GünterZöchbauer , is what I was looking for.